# I have to put the humidifier higher than normal. my problem is, I cannot place my humidistat higher than the humidifier. Can I do this

Tags: furnace

my furnace is in a closet. I have to place the humidifier higher up than just above the coils. Because of this, I cannot place my humidistat higher than the humidifier unit. It has to be lower or I cannot reach it without a small ladder. Will I lose any effciency if I place it BELOW the humidifier on the return side.

Comment: Why do you have to place the  humidistat higher then the humidifier unit? Placing it below the humidifier should be OK.